# Accessing a variable concurrently from two threads in java

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization

I am aware that there are already a lot of similar questions on the internet, but my question is about my code, NOT ABOUT THREADS. I am making a small app that has a database of players. The code of the data storing class is as follows.

```
public class DataManager 
{
static final int NO_OF_COLUMNS = 18;
static QDatabase pdb;

public DataManager()
{
    pdb = new QDatabase(NO_OF_COLUMNS);
}

public void addPlayer(Object[] playerData)
{
    pdb.add(playerData);
}

public void editPlayerInfo(int type, int playerRegNo, Object data)
{
    pdb.set(type, playerRegNo, data);
}

public int getPlayerRegNo(String userID)
{
    return (int) pdb.getData(USER_ID, userID, REG_NO);
}

public Boolean contains(int column, Object data)
{
    return pdb.contains(column, data);
}
}
```

I have a server which keeps on recieving requests from multiple clients and creating a new thread for each of them. They all access this DataManager class which essentially acts as a database. Will it be possible for me to, in some way, make it possible for all the threads to be able to call the `addPlayer()` and `editPlayerInfo()` methods at the same time and yet not mess the whole thing up due to synchronization problems?

I also know that I can use databases. But here, I just thought that this would be easier. Assume that there will be about 200 threads running simultaneously. What is the best way for me to solve this?

Is there any way for me to hve all the threads access it at the same time as otherwise having 200 threads to wait on each other might become very slow?

EDIT 1:
The QDatabase class is as follows:

```
public class QDatabase implements Serializable
{
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> database;
    public final int NOT_EXISTS = 0, REGULAR = 0, TRANSPOSE = 1;
    private int lastid = -1;

    //Initializer taking the number of columns as an argument
    public QDatabase(int noofcolumns)
    {
        database = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
        addColumns(noofcolumns);
    }

    //Method that adds an array of objects as a new row in the database.
    public void add(Object[] object)
    {
        for(int index = 0; index < database.size(); index++)
        {
            if(object != null)
            {
                database.get(index).add(object[index]);
                lastid = database.get(0).indexOf(object[0]);
            }
        }
    }

    //Method that finds the row in a column where an instance of a particular object is found and get the values at a 
    //cell with the same row and a given column.
    public Object getData(int columntocheck, Object check, int columntoget)
    {
        Object ramobject = null;

        int loc = database.get(columntocheck).indexOf(check);
        ramobject = database.get(columntoget).get(loc);

        return ramobject;
    }

    //Method to check if a column contains an instance of a given object.
    public Boolean contains(int column, Object objecttocheck)
    {
        return database.get(column).contains(objecttocheck);
    }

    //Method to set a given cell to an object.
    public void set(int column, int row, Object object)
    {
        database.get(column).set(row, object);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QDatabase is not thread-safe. You need either synchronize all its methods or use a thread-safe variant of ArrayList - CopyOnWriteArrayList from java.util.concurrent package. But be careful, using CopyOnWriteArrayList makes sense only if the number of reads from DB vastly outnumbers the number of writes. See API, it creates a fresh copy of unerlying array on all mutative operations.

**UPDATE:**

Actually, the most efficient solutiion in your situation seems to be ReadWriteLock. Use ReadLock for all reading operations and WriteLock for all mutative operations, like this

```
public class QDatabase implements Serializable {
    private ReadWriteLock readWriteLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    private Lock readLock = readWriteLock.readLock();
    private Lock writeLock = readWriteLock.writeLock();
...
    public void add(Object[] object) {
        writeLock.lock();
        try {
            ...
        }
        } finally {
            writeLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public Object getData(int columntocheck, Object check, int columntoget) {
        readLock.lock();
        try {
            ...
        } finally {
            readLock.unlock();
        }
    }
...
```

Comment: I need multiple threads to access the same database. Its a server. So then, what do I need to do?

Comment: Leave it as is. This class is OK for concurrent usage.

Comment: Could you explain how this class is OK for concurrent usage? What would happen if 2 or more threads call editPlayerInfo at the same time?

Comment: It all depends on QDatabase. Can you give me a reference to it? Or is it your own class?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It is my own class and is nothing but a manager class for a "ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>"

Comment: You should add it to the answer, because this is where sync problems may occur, not in DataManager.

Comment: QDatabase is 500 lines long. I will post what I can.

Comment: This is for a game. I can use this for the player database since it does not need to be modified often. But for the game database which needs to be modified often, what do i do?

Comment: If modifications are not often then CopyOnWriteArrayList is OK. Otherwise just synchronize all QDatabase methods. Remember that CopyOnWriteArrayList creates a copy of underlying array on each write.

Comment: I read about the Copyonwritearraylist, but i have a few questions. It is the exact same as a regular arraylist except that when the is a write, it is done on a copied array which is merged with the original array when there are no other *write* requests. Right?

Comment: I read the api description and please tell me if this is correct: Whenever a read operation occurs, the reading takes place from a copy of the array. Whenever a write operation takes place, he original array is modified, but the modification does not reflect on the copy of the array. Only the next time that a read operation is requested, the modifications are reflected.  Correct?

Comment: All mutative operations use lock.lock() (its from src), that is when one thread modifies the array others are simply blocked. no need for merging

Comment: Ok, so essentially, writing is *synchronized* but a copy is created each time for reading. Correct?

Comment: In your example, information can be read from the database only one at a time, right? And when I use the lock method, what exactly is locked?

Comment: In general lock.lock() locks the lock, when it's locked another thread calling lock.lock() will be blocked till thread 1 unlocks. But readLock works differently, you need to read ReadWriteLock API, or a tutorial, there are many on inet

Comment: A few questions : 1. If the readlock is held and a writelock is requested, what happens? 2. If the writelock is held and the readlock is requested, what happens?

Comment: 1) writeLock blocks 2) readLock blocks 3) BUT if readLock is held and readLock is requsted it doesn't block

Comment: OK, so I am using *fair mode* and one last time, the code you posted is 1.readlock held = writelock blocks and readlock allowed. 2. writelock held = writelock blocks and readlock blocks. Right?

Comment: Yes. What is important - if there is no writing reading threads work as if there's no locking at all. This is the idea of ReadWriteLock

Answer (score 0):

just add synchronized block

```
public synchronized void addPlayer(Object[] playerData)
{
    pdb.add(playerData);
}

public synchronized void editPlayerInfo(int type, int playerRegNo, Object data)
{
    pdb.set(type, playerRegNo, data);
}
```

It will make sure that no two threads will access this method at the same time.

Comment: Thats fine, but is it possible for me to make it such that all the threads can access the database at the SAME TIME?

Comment: @hele in that case, kindly rephrase your requirement a little bit. Do you want your addPlayer and editPlayerInfo to be threadSafe or do you want them to access these methods at the same time? All threads will be able to access the other methods at the same time, just not these two as per current code.

Comment: I would like for all the threads to be able to access the methods at the same time and not cause any problems due to this.

Comment: The problem is that the threads may want or edit or add data to the DB without destroying the integrity of the program.

Comment: @hele It has to be either of the two and not both. Since if two threads are editing the same object at the same time, you cannot predict which one will be the final result. I guess you don't need to synchronize addPlayer, but editPlayerInfo needs to be threadSafe

Comment: OK, I have one last question and then I'll accept this answer. The code which you have provided will only make sure that no more than one thread accesses that method at a time and that the other threads will "wait" in a queue to access the method right?

Comment: @hele yes, obviously. JVM will make sure that threads are put on wait, and then notified as soon as method is available for execution.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to have simultaneous access by multiple threads but yet remain thread safe is to use local variables or use ThreadLocal.
None of them is feasible in your case, so you can't achieve simultaneous access of thread, it has to be sequential.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the java.util.concurrency package. You could use classes there to manage your threading needs better.

In order for a class/ method to be "thread safe" it has to be designed so. Now, its not clear what the DATABASE object you have is doing internally but it does look like from the method names , that multiple threads ARE going to be an issue.

In order to INCREASE the number of threads , yet not keeping the ENTIRE method synchronized, look into the details of the add/edit methods implementations and , yes you would have to limit thread access to those lines of code that would cause issues.

You could use principles like multiple READ ,single WRITE locks etc.

Comment: About the multiple read and single write, is it just that the methods that write be synchronized and the reading methods not be, or is it a little more complex?